# properly setting email subject line delivered from email form

Tags: forms, email, header, subject

I have a email form for my website but here is the issue: when i receive an email, the subject line in my inbox shows whatever the user inputted as subject in the form. id like to override that so that whenever an email comes in. the subject in the email header is always "an inquiry from your website". In the message body, sure i don't mind their specific subject they entered but when I receive an email, id like consistency in my inbox.

this is the current code:

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {   if( $_SESSION['chapcha_code'] == $_POST['chapcha_code'] && !empty($_SESSION['chapcha_code'] ) ) {
$youremail = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$fromsubject = 'An inquiry from your website';
$title = $_POST['title'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$address = $_POST['address']; 
$city = $_POST['city']; 
$zip = $_POST['zip']; 
$country = $_POST['country']; 
$phone = $_POST['phone']; 
$subject = $_POST['subject']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 
$headers = "From: $nome <$mail>\r\n";

    $to = $youremail; 
    $mailsubject = 'Message received from'.$fromsubject.' Contact Page';
    $body = $fromsubject.'

    The person that contacted you is  '.$fname.' '.$lname.'
     Address: '.$address.'
    '.$city.', '.$zip.', '.$country.'
     Phone Number: '.$phone.'
     E-mail: '.$mail.'
     Subject: '.$subject.'

     Message: 
     '.$message.'

    |---------END MESSAGE----------|'; 
echo "Thank you for inquiring. We will contact you shortly.<br/>You may return to our <a href='/index.html'>Home Page</a>"; 
                                mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
        unset($_SESSION['chapcha_code']);
   } else {
        echo 'Sorry, you have provided an invalid security code';
   }
 } else { 
echo "You must write a message. </br> Please visit our <a href='/contact.html'>Contact Page</a> and try again."; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though you have set a variable called `$subject` elsewhere.

```
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
```

and then use that same variable to send your mail.

```
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Try creating another variable for the second use or changing it prior to suit your needs.

Comment: thanks for that info. Would you be able to show me how to make that adjustment. My skills are limited to html/css stuff. Im lost with this particular type of code.

Comment: so just below where you have 
`$to = $youremail; 
$mailsubject = 'Message received from'.$fromsubject.' Contact Page';
$body = $fromsubject.'`
add
`$subject = "Your Message here";`

This will reset that variable for its intended purpose.